# Sorting by Salary: Comparator shows no error, but doesn't work

Tags: java, comparator

Please, help me to understand, what I am missing.
I need to sort my Employees by salary. Trying to do it through **Comparator**. Shows no error, but no effect on output thou.

```
public class FirstActivity {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    //collection of employee
    Employee e1 = new Employee(1, "TestLead", "Microsoft", 4000.00, "Peter", "Doe", 35);
    Employee e2 = new Employee(2, "ManualTester", "Accenture", 1800.00, "Carl", "Fox", 56);
    Employee e3 = new Employee(3, "Developer", "IBM", 2100.00, "Michele", "Gilmore", 34);
    Employee e4 = new Employee(4, "Manager", "IBM", 2500.00, "Alfred", "Pink", 23);
    Employee e5 = new Employee(5, "AutomationTester", "Accenture", 2600.00, "Sam", "Bow", 40);
    
    // Initialise ArrayList
    List<Employee> employeeList = new ArrayList<Employee>();
    // add values
    employeeList.add(e1);
    employeeList.add(e2);
    employeeList.add(e3);
    employeeList.add(e4);
    employeeList.add(e5);
    
    
    // print values
    System.out.println("Workers salaries: ");

    Iterator<Employee> itr = employeeList.iterator();  
    //traverse elements of ArrayList object  
        while(itr.hasNext())
        {  
            Employee st=(Employee)itr.next();  
            System.out.println("Employees " + st.firstName + " salary is "+st.salary);
        }
        // trying to SORT by salary through this line
      employeeList.sort(Comparator.comparing(Employee::getSalary));
}
}
```

Comment: It's not like sort in javascript, the sorted list is returned from the call.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by the call? Unfortunately, I have no variable with my sorting output. Any advice? Thanks.

Comment: The method 'sort' returns a List, so if you want the sorted list you've got to assign that returned value to a variable, possibly the same instance.  Where do you want to print the sorted list?  The code above ends with the call to sort returning to nothing, no output above that call could possibly be affected.

Comment: After the sort print the list again , you will see the change!

Comment: @AdrianM. You are mistaken. The [`sort()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#sort(java.util.Comparator)) method is `void`, i.e. returns nothing. It sorts the list itself.

Comment: *"no effect on output"* Why would a sort executed *after* the output affect the output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks good.
I have tried your code and it is working fine.
you need to print your details after sorting.
I have tried like below

```
public class FirstActivity {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // collection of employee
        Employee e1 = new Employee(1, "TestLead", "Microsoft", 4000.00, "Peter", "Doe", 35);
        Employee e2 = new Employee(2, "ManualTester", "Accenture", 1800.00, "Carl", "Fox", 56);
        Employee e3 = new Employee(3, "Developer", "IBM", 2100.00, "Michele", "Gilmore", 34);
        Employee e4 = new Employee(4, "Manager", "IBM", 2500.00, "Alfred", "Pink", 23);
        Employee e5 = new Employee(5, "AutomationTester", "Accenture", 2600.00, "Sam", "Bow", 40);

        // Initialise ArrayList
        List<Employee> employeeList = new ArrayList<>();
        // add values
        employeeList.add(e1);
        employeeList.add(e2);
        employeeList.add(e3);
        employeeList.add(e4);
        employeeList.add(e5);

        // print values
        System.out.println("Workers salaries before sorting: ");

        Iterator<Employee> itr = employeeList.iterator();
        // traverse elements of ArrayList object
        while (itr.hasNext()) {
            Employee st = (Employee) itr.next();
            System.out.println("Employees " + st.firstName + " salary is "+st.salary);
        }
        // trying to SORT by salary through this line
        employeeList.sort(Comparator.comparing(Employee::getSalary));

        System.out.println("\nWorkers salaries after sorting: ");
        Iterator<Employee> itr1 = employeeList.iterator();
        // traverse elements of ArrayList object
        while (itr1.hasNext()) {
            Employee st = (Employee) itr1.next();
            System.out.println("Employees " + st.firstName + " salary is "+st.salary);
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
Workers salaries before sorting: 
Employees TestLead salary is 4000.0
Employees ManualTester salary is 1800.0
Employees Developer salary is 2100.0
Employees Manager salary is 2500.0
Employees AutomationTester salary is 2600.0

Workers salaries after sorting: 
Employees ManualTester salary is 1800.0
Employees Developer salary is 2100.0
Employees Manager salary is 2500.0
Employees AutomationTester salary is 2600.0
Employees TestLead salary is 4000.0
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I was close)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working. The thing that you did incorrect is that you are printing the list before or you need to print the list again after sort and comparator uses.

```
// trying to SORT by salary through this line
  employeeList.sort(Comparator.comparing(Employee::getSalary));
  employeeList.forEach(employee -> System.out.println("Employees " + employee.firstName + " salary is "+employee.salary));
```

Check out the code that I have tested on: [Online Salary Comparator](https://onlinegdb.com/SJeb3Sd0L)

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I appreciate that!)

Comment: It's my pleasure.